# EditText does not accept latptop keyboard input

Tags: android, android-edittext

It is weird scenario. One of my edit text is not accepting input from laptop keyboard.

Here is the XML:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/approval_footer_addinfo_ed"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/approval_footer_addinfo_comment"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/approval_footer_addinfo_star"
android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext"
android:gravity="top"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:padding="3dp" />
```

In other screen (Activity), it is working fine. Am sure emulator settings are fine.

Any suggestions.

Comment: delete the current emulator from sdk and try some other emulator

Comment: In any emulator it is not working.

Comment: Try with a real device maybe it's just a bug of the emulator.

Comment: update your sdk properly

Comment: I tried on BlueStacks and other 3rd party emulators, still not working.

Comment: @Aswin have you added any listener to your edittext.. any textChangeListener??

Comment: @CRUSADER No listeners. Am trying to get input with obj.getText().

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the `Hardware keyboard present` option  checked for your emulator.

[image]